# better way to implement inner class with listeners

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, anonymous

I have a main class with inner classes. This is a swing/GUI application.

I have inner classes that are swing related such as extending JPanel, JDialog etc...

Inside the inner classes I have anonymous classes such as action listeners which I have to set and get data from the outer class..

For example main class has inner class and inside inner class I have an anonymous listener class such as this:

```
public class Main extends JApplet {
 //etc...
  private class CTable extends JPanel {
      CDialog td;
      private JPopupMenu menu;
      public CTable(String title, AbstractTableModel tableModel) {
         //etc...
         menu = new JPopupMenu();
         JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Test");
         menu.add(menuItem);
         //etc...
         menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
              CTable.this.td = new CDialog("Test");
              CTable.this.td.setVisible(true);
           }
         });
     }

}
```

My only question is only related to whether its good practice to access the variable like this: **CTable.this.td = new CDialog("Test");
CTable.this.td.setVisible(true);**
...from anonymous classes and suggestions on different implementation strategies/design patterns.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't like to do it this way.  My main concern is what happen if some one extends your class and wants to change the way that the dialog works?  Technically, there stuck.  A getter from the main class would allow a developer to the opportunity to change this behavior without then needing to try and figure out how to change your inner class as well...and yes, I've had to copy swaggers of code for just this problem - MHO

Comment: good point regarding modularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know anonymous inner classes are the Swing idiom since forever, but I've never liked them.

Personally, I think the listeners are part of the controller.  I prefer the Swing components to be pure view and let the controller instantiate them and give them the listeners they need to act as the *controller* chooses.  Don't make the view have to worry about how it communicates with the controller or where it lives.

Comment: thanks, well I will accept your MVC answer, but other suggestions were great as well. too bad stackoverflow doesn't allow more than one answer to be "accepted"

Answer (score 0):

```
CTable.this.td.setVisible(true);
```

There is a rule called the [Law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). This states that you should only access classes directly. By stepping over several objects to get to the desired method, you're creating [tight coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) between your classes, which makes it harder to change individual classes in the future.

A design pattern I would suggest for this could be a `Proxy class`. A proxy class acts as a buffer between two classes, and means that both classes communicate with one another via the [Proxy class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)